# AspectJ Pointcut expression error

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

Spring version 2.5
AspectJ version 1.7

Facing issue with Pointcut expression

```
@Pointcut("within(com.test.service..*)")
```

Following is my Aspect class:

```
package com.test.aspect.controller;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect
public class ControllerAspects {

    @Before("publicOperationInService()")
    public void log(){
        System.out.println("**********anyPublicOperationInService()**********");
    }

    @Before("anyPublicOperation()")
    public void publicOp(){
        System.out.println("**********anyPublicOperation()**********");
    }


    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    private void anyPublicOperation() {}

    @Pointcut("within(com.test.service..*)")
    private void inService() {}

    @Pointcut("anyPublicOperation() && inService()")
    public void publicOperationInService() {}

}
```

Configuration is correct as I am able to execute:

```
@Before("anyPublicOperation()")
public void publicOp(){
    System.out.println("**********anyPublicOperation()**********");
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sooo... your problem is... what?

Comment: My code never executes the following
`@Before("publicOperationInService()")
    public void log(){
        System.out.println("**********anyPublicOperationInService()**********");
    }`

Comment: There isn't enough information here. We would need to see the method declaration for the method that is intended to be advised.